# Why is play framework 2.3 not generating getters for my models?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

I recently updated my project from version 2.2.1 to version 2.3.5 -- and after alot of hard work, I'm stuck :(

I have a buncha Junit tests that used to run fine in eclipse with 2.2.1, but now when i run those same tests in 2.3.5 i get this error:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: models.Activity.getByUser()Lmodels/embedded/reference/UserReference;
at views.html.mails.activityCommittee$.apply(activityCommittee.template.scala:28) ~[classes/:na]
at views.html.mails.activityCommittee$.render(activityCommittee.template.scala:127) ~[classes/:na]

Obviously there is not "getByUser()" method, i only have "public UserReference byUser" in my model.

And yes, I do have the Scala IDE installed and I have the correct (matching) scala version defined in my build.sbt.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try cleaning your project? Seems like your project is still compiled for older version of play. Try running `sbt clean` from project root directory.

Comment: I have encountered problems like this and running `clean` on the project under the `activator` console and restartign the server always seemed to do the trick.

Comment: Definitely try running `clean` command as guys are recommending however I would say try `play clean` command instead of `sbt clean`

Comment: When I have errors in Eclipse, I always run `activator clean eclipse`